# Rails: Can't Display Unique Images Attached to Another Variable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, image

I'm making a site where I can browse through artists, albums, and songs. When I go to an artist's show page I want it to display their albums with the cover art. I can get my webpage to show the image I want if I just use the file name, but I want a unique image to appear for each artist's album, not the same one for every album.

album.rb

```
class Album < ApplicationRecord
    has_one_attached :artwork
    belongs_to :artist
    has_many :songs
end
```

seeds.rb

```
lz = Album.create( title: "Led Zeppelin", release_date: 1969, artist_id: zepp.id, artwork: lz.jpg )
lzII = Album.create( title: "Led Zeppelin II", release_date: 1969, artist_id: zepp.id, artwork: lzII.jpg )
lzIII = Album.create( title: "Led Zeppelin III", release_date: 1970, artist_id: zepp.id, artwork: lzIII.jpg )
lzIV = Album.create( title: "Led Zeppelin IV", release_date: 1971, artist_id: zepp.id, artwork: lzIV.jpg )
album.artwork.attach(params[:artwork])
```

My artists/show.html.erb

```
<h1> <%= @artist.name %> </h1>

<% @artist.albums.each do |album| %>
    <%= image_tag (album.artwork) %>
<p> <%= link_to album.title, album_path(album) %> </p>

<% end %>
```

I get an error (Can't resolve image into URL: undefined method `persisted?')

Is there something wrong with the way I'm seeding this? I have the .jpgs in my assest/images folder with the same exact titles as the album instances.

If I add image_url like so

```
<% @artist.albums.each do |album| %>
    <%= image_tag image_url(album.artwork) %>
<p> <%= link_to album.title, album_path(album) %> </p>
<% end %>
```

I get (The asset "" is not present in the asset pipeline.)

**Edit**
Just tried to run `rails db:seed` thinking I may have forgotten to do that and got an error (undefined method assignment .jpg). Looks like it doesn't like the way I tried to connect the album to the artwork and is trying to call a jpg method instead of reading it as a file type.

Comment: Did you verify the output from `<%= image_tag image_url(album.artwork) %>` and `<%= image_tag (album.artwork) %>` match the path to the image?

Comment: I just tried going into the seeds file and changing `lz.jpg` to `image_path("/image/artwork/lz.jpg"). But it looks like image_path can't be called in the seeds file. So how do I assign the artwork param as I image in my assests from my seeds file?